# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' - when using FutureBuilder.wait()

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using futureBuilder.wait() to return two futures and call their data, I'm getting the above error when I try and call the getLatestMood function

Not sure exactly sure why its not a string and why the getData() function is a string since they both return a document from firebase?

I've added my code below any help appreciated!

```
class CorrectMood extends StatefulWidget {
  const CorrectMood({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CorrectMoodState createState() => _CorrectMoodState();
}

class _CorrectMoodState extends State<CorrectMood> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([getLatestMood(), getData()]),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
        snapshot.data![0]; //getLatestMood
        snapshot.data![1]; //getData

        if (snapshot.hasData) {

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Display the Picture'),
              backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
            ),
            // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
            // constructor with the given path to display the image.
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 20.0, 8.0, 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child:
                          Text(

                            "${snapshot.data![1].firstName}"
                                "${snapshot.data![0].prediction}"
                            //"${snapshot.data!.data()!["firstName"]} \n\n "
                                "We have predicted your mood as:\n\n "
                            //"${DatabaseService.getMood()}\n\n"
                                "Please select a reason associated to your mood",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }


}

Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() async {
  var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('USER_TABLE')
      .doc(currentUser!.uid)
      .get();
}

Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMood()  async {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userMood')
        .where('userId' == currentUser!.uid)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get();

  }

countDocuments() async {
  var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userMoods')
      .doc('useerID')
      .collection(currentUser!.uid)
      .get();

  List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.docs;

  return (_myDocCount.length);
}

Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getLatestMood() async {
  var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var latestMoodDoc = countDocuments();

  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userMood')
      .doc(currentUser!.uid) // make this the userID
      .collection(latestMoodDoc) // make this increment every time
      .doc() //this can be system generated name don't care about it
      .get();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed my query was wrong and I was in fact returning null data,
I now get type 'Future is not a subtype of type 'Widget' when trying to return data using

```
 "${snapshot.data![1]['firstName']}"
```

Comment: You need to inform what type your FutureBuilder is. Change FutureBuilder to FutureBuilder<String>

Comment: Adding that gives me the following error
The argument type 'Future<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<String>?'

Answer (score 0):

try adding .then for example:

```
String? myString;
myFutureMethod()
.then!((val){
  myString=val; //Enter your code here
}
```

Note: I haven't tested the code

Comment: What is the .then doing? not sure exactly what I should achieve with this? Is it just to assign the value from the returned document to a string?